# What are native methods in Java and where should they be used?

Tags: java, native

A native method has the same syntax as an abstract method, but where is it implemented?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

> What are native methods in Java and where should they be used?

Once you see a small example, it becomes clear:

**Main.java**:

```
public class Main {
    public native int intMethod(int i);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Main");
        System.out.println(new Main().intMethod(2));
    }
}
```

**Main.c**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intMethod(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i) {
  return i * i;
}
```

**Compile and run**:

```
javac Main.java
javah -jni Main
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
java -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

**Output**:

```
4
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45.

So it is clear that it allows you to:

- call a compiled dynamically loaded library (here written in C) with arbitrary assembly code from Java
- and get results back into Java

This could be used to:

- write faster code on a critical section with better CPU assembly instructions (not CPU portable)
- make direct system calls (not OS portable)

with the tradeoff of lower portability.

It is also possible for you to call Java from C, but you must first create a JVM in C: [How to call Java functions from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c)

[Example on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/java-cheat/tree/77437774e632ba6ecb483f6e69726431a23b5808/jni) for you to play with.

Comment: it's working fine.....you did a great job bro... I have tried for so many tutorials but didn't get a working example

Comment: @dom thanks! I guess it's because it's highly system dependent stuff. That is why I always say the distro version tested on :-)

Comment: @Ciro: what is JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL. Is it a syntax used for a native application.

Comment: @niks stuff defined inside `jni.h`. Looks like the recommended / most portable way of doing it. Don't know where it is documented, would appreciate a link.

Answer (score 46):

The method is implemented in "native" code. That is, code that does not run in the JVM. It's typically written in C or C++.

Native methods are usually used to interface with system calls or libraries written in other programming languages.

Comment: you mean if i have a native method forName in my class, the implement of it is a part of system call. Should the native methods to be used same as name of the system calls

Comment: Not exactly. If you have a method named "forName" in a class called "com.example.Foo" the C function that will get called will be named something like "Java_com_example_Foo_forName". That function could then in turn invoke system calls. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html for more details.

Comment: if the native method is implemented with other name as in ur example Java_com_example_Foo_forName in C, how do we know that the name for the native method (forName) we have given is exactly used. I mean here is Java_com_example_Foo_forName has completely different name which can look like a local method in C which one can get confused in understanding it as an implementation of its own method rather than the implementation with the same name. what u have explained i got it clearly but I am unable to catch how does implementation goes part.

Comment: In general, you can't tell what the native method will call without looking at the documentation and/or source, just like any other method. Just because it's called "forName" doesn't mean it will call a system call of that name, but one would hope the author would have used a reasonable naming convention. Incidentally, when I said they're used to interface with system calls, I did not mean to say that they are one-to-one with system calls, necessarily. Interfacing with system calls is just a common use of native methods.

Comment: Say we want to call some system function, `baz`. First, create a class called `com.example.Foo` with native method `bar`. Then write a C function, `Java_com_example_Foo_bar` which calls `baz`. Compile and link that C function into a shared library (eg: `libquux.so` or `quux.dll`). Your Java code would have to invoke `System.loadLibrary(“quux”)` before the `bar` native method is invoked (or an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` will be thrown). I've made names different whenever allowed in this example, but in practice the class and library would have similar names, as would the function and method.

Comment: spot on example Laurence got the concept cleared.

Answer (score 17):

> I like to know where does we use Native Methods

Ideally, not at all.  In reality some functionality is not available in Java and you have to call some C code.

The methods are implemented in C code.

Comment: Upvote for your sense of humour (The first Line)

Answer (score 6):

Java native code necessities:

- h/w access and control.
- use of commercial s/w and system services[h/w related].
- use of legacy s/w that hasn't or cannot be ported to Java.
- Using native code to perform time-critical tasks.

hope these points answers your question :)

Comment: What about I/O? Or does this go under "use of legacy s/w that hasn't or cannot be ported to Java". I wonder because the FileNotFoundException class has native I/O methods.

Comment: @RnBandCrunk : yes you are correct. I/O is typically system-dependent, native methods must be used to implement those operations.

Answer (score 4):

Native methods allow you to use code from other languages such as C or C++ in your java code. You use them when java doesn't provide the functionality that you need. For example, if I were writing a program to calculate some equation and create a line graph of it, I would use java, because it is the language I am best in. However, I am also proficient in C. Say in part of my program I need to calculate a really complex equation. I would use a native method for this, because I know some C++ and I know that C++ is much faster than java, so if I wrote my method in C++ it would be quicker. Also, say I want to interact with another program or device. This would also use a native method, because C++ has something called pointers, which would let me do that.