# What are the benefits of using interface without any methods ? In php

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, interface, multiple-inheritance

AS I was looking at code in Laravel 5 project, I encountered with a class
Like below --

```
class Abc extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued
{

}
```

And where Interfaces are like below -

```
interface SelfHandling {}
interface ShouldBeQueued {}
```

I got confused if it does not have any methods then what's the use of these 
interfaces ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface with no methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878039/interface-with-no-methods). They call them "[Marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)".

Answer (score 1):

It allows to handle objects by behavior. Say you have an array of objects implementing different interface, you can then differentiate them doing this :

```
if($obj instanceof ShouldBeQueued){
    //do something
}
else if{$obj instanceof SelfHandling){
    //do something else
}
```

This example is a bit crude, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: so what should be the case if i create an instance of Abc class, Can it be an instance of both ShouldBeQueued and  SelfHandling well ? then there is no meaning for if and else if as it will fall in both cases ?

Comment: Bear in mind it is just a crude example. But, you could have objects that implement one, both, or none of this interface and process them accordingly.

Comment: Someone came up with a better answer than me : http://wpkrauts.com/2013/how-to-build-flexible-php-interfaces/#interfaces-with-no-methods. In your case, I think it's in order to use internal types

Answer (score 0):

They are used as sort of a "flag". It can be checked by doing `$command instanceof ShouldBeQueued`.

The alternative would be to include a method, but that would require multiple lines of redundant code. (Most implementations would return `true` anyway.)

```
interface ShouldBeQueued
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    function shouldBeQueued();
}

class Abc extends Command implements ShouldBeQueued
{
    function shouldBeQueued()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Checking it would be a bit more complicated as well:

```
if ($command instanceof ShouldBeQueued && $command->shouldBeQueued()) { /*...*/ }
```

Whether it is a good practice is another matter.