# Is it sensible to use the hash code of a class as its serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization

I've noticed that in my company's codebase, a common pattern is to set the `serialVersionUID` of a class to the hash code of the class, like this:

```
public final class ClassName implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ClassName.class.hashCode();

    [...]

}
```

Is this a valid approach for setting a class' `serialVersionUID`?

Comment: Well, `Class.hashCode()` actually is `Object.hashCode()` so it depends on the memory location that class resides in. That being said you probably realize that's not actually a good value to use as it would probably differ between runs. However, since the old serialization mechanism is deprecated anyway you can also just not use `serialVersionUID` anymore (or use some default value).

Comment: There are plugins for IDE that help you to generate `serialVersionUID`. For example [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/185-generateserialversionuid) for IntelliJ

Comment: @Thomas: "hashCode may *or may not* be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time.", emphasis mine.

Answer (score 6):

[`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) has no explicitly defined `hashCode()` method, so it's not defined to be stable.

That means that you can (and probably will) get different results for `MyClass.class.hashCode()` between different runs, even on the same JVM and *definitely* between different JVM implementations and/or versions.

This means that the serialized data from any one JVM will likely only be usable within that same JVM.

Now that *might* be used as an intentional way of avoiding the use of serialization for cross-VM communication (it's not a "security mechanism" or anything like that, but it can be used to quickly detect attempts to use serialization for cross-VM communication). But if that is the goal then flat out using a random number is probably better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible idea. There are multiple strategies of how a `hashCode` is computed (`Class::hashCode` is `Object::hashCode`). Under java-8 the default is Marsaglia-XOR-Shift, a pseudo-random generator that will get you an `int`; but that is subject to change from VM-to-VM and there are multiple ways to alter that from the same version too, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175508/1059372) for details.