# How is it possible to call a native methods from java class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> Android\Sdk\sources\android-27\java\lang\String.java

```
@FastNative
public native String concat(String str);
```

1. Why Android Studio `Cannot resolve symbol` `@FastNative`?
2. How is that this java method could call a native method without mentioning the class or package containing the `concat` method in the native code?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900736/what-are-native-methods-in-java-and-where-should-they-be-used

Comment: Native method forces the loader to look for the `concat` method in `String` class of native library? In that answer there is a loader in the java class, what is the equivalent of that loader in Android?