# When or which type of java packages are called native?

Tags: java, regex, java-package

Recently I was improving my understanding on Regular Expressions by reading Mastering Regular Expressions Third Edition by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl, there is mentions **Java has had a native regex package** . Can some one please explain me what kind of java packages are known as native ?

Attaching image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Have you try google already? Regex and Java posts and pages are quite abundant. You are expected to do some research before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: This is an inaccurate statement. The `native` keyword is applicable to the methods only. Perhaps, he meant that all the methods of classes were `native` so he stated that the package itself is native. I suggest you to look for more `native` methods if interested. Take a look on `Math.java` class.

Comment: @Nikolas Exactly how many native methods are in `java.lang.Math`?

Comment: I just create a program and type `import java.util.regex.Matcher;`. So it is native.

Comment: @lexicore: No method at all - it’s a place to start exploring. These methods are not native but vast majority of them indirectly refer to theirs native implementations - that’s why I suggest to start there and u derstand the whole context.

Comment: @Closers The question is pretty clear and well formulated.

Comment: @Nikolas It's just a bit strange that you suggest to lok for more `native` methods and point to `java.lang.Math` which hase zero `native` methods.

Comment: @lexicore: I gave you my explanation. Perhaps, I chose the wrong words and made you misunderstood my intent.

Comment: In this context, it just means that the package comes with the JDK already included and there are no additional packages or JARs that you need to download and install, like you do for `javax.servlet` or Java EE packages. Even `javax.xml` and `java.util.logging` used to be separate packages that you had to download, but now they come 'native' with the JDK installation. Usually any useful packages are rolled into the JDK and come pre-installed, similar to how Microsoft buys companies and puts the features into the Windows OS.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear to a native English speaker who knows Java history, but I'll still vote to leave closed because it's not a very useful question.

Answer (score 2):

*Native* in this case means packages which are built-in or provided by the JRE. I.e. packages for which you don't need to import additional libraries.

This is not to be mistaken with [`native` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900736/what-are-native-methods-in-java-and-where-should-they-be-used).

The usage of the work *native* in the first sense is not normative. That is, JLS does not provide this definition. It's more colloquial.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.