# A few questions about loading libraries and native methods in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Part of my tries to understand why my code is hanging when running in different OS, I had to debug different eclipse plugins. I saw the following code in some Java file:

```
Library.loadLibrary("swt")
```

Based on [What are native methods in Java and where should they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900736/what-are-native-methods-in-java-and-where-should-they-be-used), I understand that native methods are used to execute functions written in different programming languages. But I have two question regarding it:

1. When `loadLibrary` is called with the input `"swt"`, what actually happens? Where `loadLibrary` looks for SWT library and how can I change it? What is the equivalent command in Linux to get the library (I guess it's some shared library)?
2. Consider the following code:

```
    public static final native void _gtk_widget_destroy(long /*int*/ widget);
    public static final void gtk_widget_destroy(long /*int*/ widget) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            _gtk_widget_destroy(widget);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
   }
```

The `_gtk_widget_destroy` method is native. Does it mean that there is a method in another language (probably C) that is called `_gtk_widget_destroy`? How do I know from which library this method is coming from (maybe SWT)?

Comment: On java 15 and later, you can use the flag `-Xlog:library=info` to print info about library and native method loading. That will show you which library contains the implementation for the native method.

Comment: @JornVernee Unfortunately we are using OpenJDK 8

Answer (score 1):

`System.loadLibrary("X")` uses `System#mapLibraryName` to construct the actual library name. On Linux this is `libX.so`, on Mac it would be `libX.dylib`, and on Windows it is `libX.dll`.

It then searches for a library with that name in each entry of `java.library.path` (a VM property).

For your second question: you need the full namespace and class name of the surrounding class as well. A quick search tells me the full name of that method is `org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK#_gtk_widget_destroy`.
Now, there are two options:

- Either `libswt.so` calls `RegisterNatives` to bind this method to a function pointer (typically in its `JNI_OnLoad` method.) [This is not the case.](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/975011388a62584b52141fff2fa5c3d16ff4ec33/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/common/library/swt.c)
- It uses the common name mangling scheme, which would result in a symbol with the name `Java__org_eclipse_swt_internal_gtk_GTK_1gtk_1widget_1destroy`. It seems the developers have abstracted that long name into [a macro](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/gtk/library/gtk3.c#L2057). You can use the standard `nm` tool to determine whether a given .so file contains that symbol.