# How to debug hanging in a GTK based application?

Tags: java, user-interface, gtk

My application is written in Java 8 and the GUI is built upon the Eclipse plug-ins. On some of the OS versions, the application works perfectly, without any problems in the GUI. But on SUSE SLSE12 the application is hanging after being opened for a few hours. By hanging I mean, the GUI is getting stuck for a few minutes after closing some widget.

It's hard to figure out what's the reason, but after some debugging I noticed the code is getting stuck for a few minutes when we call the `dispose` method of package [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell](https://github.com/shy942/Swt3.1Git/blob/06bb55f672287afe9b628a5b5dd050899f55bcdd/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.java) to destroy the widget. After some additional debugging, I noticed that the hanging is coming from the following code:

```
public static final native void _gtk_widget_destroy(long /*int*/ widget);
public static final void gtk_widget_destroy(long /*int*/ widget) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        _gtk_widget_destroy(widget);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

And as I understand, it uses the `lock` variable that is coming from [Platform.java](https://github.com/shy942/Swt3.1Git/blob/06bb55f672287afe9b628a5b5dd050899f55bcdd/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/gtk/org/eclipse/swt/internal/Platform.java) to lock and then calls the native `_gtk_widget_destroy` method to destroy the widget. I actually asked how this method works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438838/a-few-questions-about-loading-libraries-and-native-methods-in-java/72444049#72444049). But now I'm trying how to fix the hanging.

I believe the reason for this hanging is the GTK version I'm using or rather the shared library from which the `_gtk_widget_destroy` function is coming from. At the end, it destroys the widget, but it takes a lot of time (up to 5 minutes) and a lot of users having this issue with out application. I haved tried to set different GTK version by setting the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but all of them lead to that slowness and even different issues with the GUI (missing components, etc).

In the previous question I asked about the `_gtk_widget_destroy` method and how to find the location of it. The `nm` command was suggested and I found out that those methods are coming from shared libs of format `libgtk-.*`

Since I tried to change the GTK version multiple times I'm not sure what else I can do. Some technical aspects:

- I'm using [Eclipse 4.8](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.8-201806110500/) with `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.107.0.v20180611-0422`.
- As I understand, that eclipse version requires GTK 2.24 version. I'm using GTK 2.24.20 and it works great on one OS operation. But on SLES12 I don't have it installed by IT, but I did tried `2.24.32`, `3.22.28` and `3.24.23`.
- I also tried to migrate to Eclipse 4.10 but it didn't solve the problem.
- I also tried to use the `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` option but when my GUI is getting stuck, the GTK interactive GUI also getting stuck.

How one can debug such strange issue?

Please note that the links that I posted in this question are leading to some Github project that installed the same plugins that I did (just for you to easier understand the structure of the plugins).

Comment: Is it due to the call to `_gtk_widget_destroy` or the `lock`?  I would try to log around these variables.

Comment: @JohnKoch Thanks for the comment. I logged the code and it's definitely coming from `_gtk_widget_destroy `. The `lock` and `unlock` both take around 0 milliseconds to run. While `_gtk_widget_destroy ` takes 630 milliseconds (before getting into the slowness - tested at start).