# Call Java function from C++ method

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am facing trouble calling a Java function from C++ method. The following is what I am doing

My java class

```
package com.q.IT;

public class Carv {

public boolean isValidRatio(float a, float b)
{

       //do something
       return True;
    }
}
```

My C++ method

```
void printAndValidateResults() {

    JNIEnv *env;
jclass ItClass =env->FindClass("com/q/IT/Carv");
jobject object = env->AllocObject(ItClass);
jmethodID isValidRatioID = env->GetMethodID(ItClass,"isValidRatio", "(FF)Z");
    bool retVal = env->CallBooleanMethod(object, isValidRatioID, 1.0f,2.0f);
}
```

I get the following error

```
06-23 23:35:03.459: A/libc(15758): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xe92d43a4 (code=1), thread 16113 (AsyncTask #2)
```

As you can see, the C++ method is a normal C++ method and not something like

`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_q_IT_blahblah(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{`

, I'd like to keep it that way. The crash happens here

```
jclass ItClass =env->FindClass("com/q/IT/Carv");
```

I am not quite sure what to initialize *env to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, check [Creating a JVM from C](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html). It shows a sample procedure to create a JVM and invoke a method. If the JVM already exists; e.g. your C program is invoked by the Java program (callback situation), you can cache the JNIEnv* pointer.

As an advice, be careful caching pointers to the JVM from C/C++, there are some semantics involved as to what you can cache and it could be invoked later on.

Source: [How to call Java functions from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c)

Answer (score 3):

Your pointer isn't initialized :

```
JNIEnv *env;
jclass ItClass =env->FindClass("com/q/IT/Carv"); // env has not been set
```

You have to use the `JNIEnv` pointer that you get from the JNI call if you want to be able to communicate with your Java code.