# How to call a Java method in a C/C++ file?

Tags: java-native-interface

Say I have a jar file, there is a class named A in the package of the jar. I have to call a method of the class A like:

```
A.getInstance->notifyState(int)
```

in a C/C++ file, how to solve this?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c