# Use Java as “scripting” language in C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Let’s say I’m designing a cross-platform application in C++ that can be user-extended through add-ons. The application then offer a C++ API and will load dynamic objects (`.so`, `.dll`, etc.). But, this is cumbersome for users to have to compile for the 6 target platforms (Windows `x86`/`x86-64`, MacOS X `x86`/`x86-64` and GNU/Linux `x86`/`x86-64`).

In order to keep portability, I thought of providing a **Ruby API** using `libruby`. With a little work I came with a proof of concept. The problem is that I’m worried about **performances**. These add-ons may get big and *CRuby* isn't that fast.

Then I thought, why not **Java**?

- Java bytecode has better runtime performances, especially with JIT;
- It is portable;
- Distribution is simple, users only have to provide a `jar`;
- Users can provide closed-source add-ons (even if decompiling Java bytecode is not that hard);
- More people know about Java than Ruby.

The question is now, how to achieve this? I made some research and only found out about **JNI** (*Java native interface*). This seems, though, to be able to “call” C++ from Java and not the other way around.

Comment: Please check this earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JNI Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html), which allows you to launch a VM from C or C++.

Once you've launched the VM, the [JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) lists many other C functions for interacting with Java.

> I made some research and only found out about JNI (Java native interface). This seems, though, to be able to “call” C++ from Java and not the other way around.

You're probably looking at native functions, which allow you to define Java methods in C.