# Is the source code of native methods available?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

At first I want to let you know that this question is not related with [What is native implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557574/what-is-native-implementation-in-java). I got many useful information from that thread.

I want to know that are the codes of the native implementations available? I have jdk source code but I can not find the native codes for `System.currentTimeMillis` or `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` or other native method.

Comment: You can download the source for the entire OpenJDK and have it open as another project if you have the memory (At least I do. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey are you referring http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/ ?

Comment: Yes the bundle is 4 months old and you can also download the latest from source control but its unlikely to matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, see [os::javaTimeMillis](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp#l1805) in `/src/os/solaris/vm/os_solaris.cpp` to see the Solaris implementation for instance.

There are a few layers of wrappers to get there though, see [JVM_CurrentTimeMillis](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l286) in `/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

Because the underlying methods are intrinsic to the OS you are running Java on, you will not find their source code in the JDK documentation. I suppose you'd need to find out exactly which procedures are called on your platform, and if source code is available for those (which strongly depends on your OS).