# Where can I see the definitions of native methods in java?

Tags: java, native

Using eclipse, I see that methods like `System.nanotime()` or `System.arraycopy()` are native.
However I could not see the definitions of these methods.
Where are can I find the definitions , and more importantly what language are those methods written in ?

Comment: Surely the clue is in the name - `native`. The methods are written in C or C++ tailored to the platform in question. The code depends on the exact version of the JRE you are using and the platform you are using it on.

Answer (score -1):

Install the Java SE Development Kit from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp.
Once installed, you should find an archive called **src.zip** in the top of the JDK installation directory. The Java source code is in there.

Comment: These don't contain the **native** sources. Although the asker used the term *"definitions"*, which may be misleading, he most likely was looking for something like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6502320