# Java - Store byte array as String in DB and create byte array using String value

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have a byte array with the value `[B@6c89db9a` I have stored this value in a MySQL db as a string representation - `mybyteArray.toString()`

I would like to retrieve the saved value from the database and create a new byte array using the string value of the original byte array.

I have tried the examples [Java Byte Array to String to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array)

and [byte to string and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290533/byte-to-string-and-vice-versa)

However i am not getting the original byte array value. It is generating a different value. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: *I have a byte array with the value [B@6c89db9a I have stored this value ...* ... that's not a value. It's a completely useless (outside of Java) hashcode. The `toString()` method of an array does *not* print the contents of an array.

Comment: yes, i am using it for authentication therefore i need to store it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have a byte array with the value [B@6c89db9a I have stored this value ...

That's not a value. It's a completely useless (outside of Java) hashcode. The `toString()` method of an array does *not* print the contents of an array. Arrays do not override `toString()` and therefore `Object.toString()` is called.

If you wish to store an array of arbitrary bytes in MySQL you would want to use a `BLOB` type (or maybe `VARBINARY`? it's been a while since I've used MySQL but it appears from a quick google they're basically the same in modern versions) in your table, and store the bytes:

> create table example (some_bytes BLOB);

Your prepared statement would look like:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO example (some_bytes) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

And you'd insert those bytes via:

```
pstmt.setBytes(1, myByteArray);
pstmt.execute();
```

**Edit to add from comments:** You have some bytes in an array. If those bytes represent a string of characters and you know what the character set is, you convert them to a `String` using the `String` constructor that takes a character set:

```
String myString = new String(bytes, knownCharset);
```

For example, if they represent a UTF-8 string you would use:

```
String myString = new String(byteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I am using a framework which doesnt support BLOB or CLOB. Therefore i thought that i could store the byte array using toString in the db and retrieve the string and recreate the original byte array. Is that possible?

Comment: You thought ... wrong. The result of an array's `toString()` is completely and utterly meaningless outside of the JVM internals.

Comment: OK so can you suggest how I can store the byte array in the dB without using blob etc?

Comment: My answer covers the two possible solutions. The only other (ridiculous, hacky, no-one-would-ever-do-that) thing you could do is convert the byte array to an array of numbers in JSON and store it that way.

Answer (score 4):

For the record:

another solution would be to store the base64 encoded byte array, see
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

The question is too old, so I'm not going to elaborate on this .

Answer (score 0):

According to [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)-

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.
>
> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Therefore what you are saving **does not** contain the **real** value of your byte array.

Comment: I cant use CLOB or BLOB due to a framework restriction. I am trying to save the binary array value in the DB as a string. Then retrieve the saved value and put it back as a byte array. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try two functions below to finish your transform jobs:

```
    public static byte[] toBytes(String s) {
    try {
      return s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      System.out.println("UTF-8 not supported?", e);
      return null;
    }
    } 

      public static String toString(final byte [] b, int off, int len) {
          if (b == null) {
             return null;
          }
          if (len == 0) {
             return "";
          }
          try {
            return new String(b, off, len, "UTF8");
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          System.out.println("UTF-8 not supported?", e);
          return null;
          }
      }
```