# how to write java code to print a string without using any built-in function like println etc

Tags: java

I have no idea how to start writing a java code to print
a string without using any inbuilt function like println etc.

Does anyone know how to write it?

Comment: what is the motivation behind this requirement?

Comment: You can't do anything very much, in any programming language, without using some kind of "inbuilt function".  What exactly is the point of this question?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not paste you all the article you can read here: http://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/

But read it and look the repetition of "native" word.

Then you can jump to this other post : [What is a native implementation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557574/what-is-native-implementation-in-java)

Then, you will have the presumption that you cannot write to process standard stream (or error) without using any native function, because you need something runnable on different OS... and that's the goal of the JVM.

Answer (score -1):

You can write it using PrintWriter class

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        printWriter.write("Hello");
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but those are "inbuilt functions".

Comment: those who are  inbuilt function like println, even you native code of c or c++ you will use it's print method. or Java stream like PrintStream 0r PrintWrite is a stream or Out object, then you will use it write or method

Comment: BTW why you down voted ???

Comment: If you're asking *me* that, then I'm tempted to actually downvote just for your failure to read any of my comment.